# Is it possible to SHOW CREATE TABLE including the schema name?

Tags: mysql

I can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to display the SQL necessary to create the given table:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE acme.User;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
```

**Is it possible to get the schema name in the output as well?** Like:

```
CREATE TABLE `acme`.`User` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
```

I tried running the query from another schema, but the output is the same.

Comment: This is a tough one.  I was thinking I could use some replace magic and combine `DATABASE()` with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but, I can't seem to get the latter to store into a variable or be combinable at all.

Comment: I can programmatically add it alright (not in MySQL), as the output is really predictable. But I was wondering if MySQL had a built-in way to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to do so.

Sure, we can programmatically add the schema name after `CREATE TABLE`, but there is more to it: **foreign keys**.

If the table contains foreign keys, the output does not contain the schema of the target table either, unless the target table is not in the same schema as the base table.

In any case, the current schema when `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is executed does not matter.

I've written some code to handle the schema name [here](https://github.com/BenMorel/smartdump/blob/ddf330630987ccda394eec1ca0c3fb6c75cfdb46/src/Driver/MySQLDriver.php#L129-L178).